# What is exact size of figure from Matlab to add in latex

Tags: wrapfigure

I want to add some results (graphs) from Matlab in(.eps format).I dnt know what should be the size of the figures. Every time I add figure in latex my supervisor says change the size. Does any one know the standard size of image , size titles in graphs and size of values on axis. Any idea please?

Comment: The ask your supervisor which size is preferred. If they are vector graphics you can always scale them up if they are too small

Comment: Related: [PlotPub: Publication quality graphs in MATLAB](https://github.com/masumhabib/PlotPub) can set a figure size in inches. There are lower-level ways of doing this, too.

Comment: You are lucky enough to have a supervisor who cares a bit. I would suggest that you use the `matlab2tikz` http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz toolbox (to get your data in the appropriate format) and then the `pgfplots` package. It requires a bit of tuning at the beginning but then you will never turn back...

Comment: Is there any news here? The question is opinion based right now.

Comment: There's isn't really any standard size, it depends on the context. For example, a figure that should fit in a single column of a two column document must be narrower than one that should fit across both columns.    And the data you're trying to visualize may also influence the decision, in some cases a larger figure is needed to make it legible, in some cases a smaller figure is sufficient, which lets you save room.